# How do I reset/reinstall Safari without opening it?

Tags: safari, apple-silicon

macOS 12.0.1
M1 MacBook Pro 13"

Every time I try to open the Safari browser it starts opening an infinite number of tabs of my previously opened tabs. This eventually freezes up the computer unless I quickly force kill Safari.

All searches online point how to reset Safari after opening it. Is there a way I can do this without opening the Safari browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Late edit:* The simpler way to do this for a one-time clear of the saved state is to hold shift as you launch it. This should work for any app.

Clear the saved state files so that it doesn't try to reopen those tabs next time it starts.

From Finder:

- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>     <kbd>G</kbd>
- Copy/paste `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Safari.savedState`

Delete **the contents** of that folder [data, window_7, windows] not the entire folder, as it's an alias. The next start of Safari should be clean.

Comment: Isn't there a key that you hold down when launching to stop previous windows opening?

Comment: @benwiggy - Not that I know of. It's usually Opt, for things like Mail or Photos. Doesn't seem to work on Safari. it may have cleared caches, as pages took a bit longer to load up after I tried it.

Comment: Yes, launch Safari while holding SHIFT. That is safe mode for Safari

Comment: Can someone test the Shift key works through a second relaunch, as opposed to then 'remembering' all the opened tabs from earlier? I have way too many tabs open to lose them in an experiment. I confirmed it works through a single relaunch, but then I have to use 'Reopen all Windows from last session' & I absolutely don't want to lose those by running it twice, just in case.

Comment: That didn't work. Tried again after restarting too. I have the "submit report" report after I force killed safari after it went rogue once again. Will that help?

Comment: Ok. Just tried 'shift' and double click to open and it opened perfectly fine. Funny thing is I quit safari after that without doing anything and opened it the normal way once again and it's working perfectly fine now!